# Rails form_for change submit routing

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form in my rails app that I would like to route to a simple "Thank you" page when the user hits submit. I've seen that you can route to other actions with `form_for` but I can't figure out how to route to a simple HTML page.

Here is the page with my form

```
<html>
    <body style="text-align:center">
        <br>
      <h2>
        On a scale from 1-10, how likely are you to recommend this site to a friend or colleague?
      </h2>
      <br>
      <%= form_for @score do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :site_id %> 
            <%= f.select(:value, (1..10).to_a) %>
            <br>
                <h2>
            Thank you! Would you care to explain why you chose that?
            </h2>
            <br>
            <%= f.text_area :response %>        
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
        <% end %>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just redirect from the create action after saving the review?

Comment: What about using JS to simply display a thank you after the form is submitted? Could that be possible too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
<%= form_for @score, url: "/thankyou.html" do |f| %>
```

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html